# SQL connection string parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net

Which of the following parameters of Connection String is used to specify the name of the database?
a) Database
b) Initial catalogue
c) Data Source
d) Provider

Comment: Is this a quiz?

Comment: Okay, the answer is B :)

Comment: Google "Connection String parameters" -> results 2-4 explain. This is the best: https://www.connectionstrings.com/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords/
Please, please, try harder next time.

Comment: Also, look at the SqlConnectionStringBuilder if you want to make your life easier.

Comment: Also, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
The title of your post says nothing of what you're doing. We know it's C#/.NET related by the fact that you've tagged it as such.

Comment: @john what if 2 options have to be selected?

Comment: @DEVANSHGUPTA I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @john I mean two of the above four options are correct. One is INITIAL CATALOGUE and what could be the other correct option?

Comment: Nooooo You just copy/pasted?!?! `-1` and I wish I could add a few zer0s to it...

Comment: show your connection string and mention your database name.

Answer (score 2):

To completely answer your question, here is an example of connection string:

```
Data Source=localhost\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks
```

- Data Source is your server name, usually your localhost.
- Initial Catalog is the name of your database.
- Database is a collection of pieces of information that is organized and used on a computer.
- Provider name is used to set the name of the .NET Framework data provider that the DataSource control uses to connect to an underlying data source. If no provider is set, the default is the ADO.NET provider for Microsoft SQL Server.

I hope it helps in your understanding.

Comment: I think it was either a talk show, or a joke... definitely not a quiz though. Maybe a test but no, probably a joke.... hmmmmm